# BlackBerry simulator settings for VPN

Tags: blackberry, blackberry-simulator, blackberry-eclipse-plugin

I want to test a project from the BlackBerry simulator, but our webservice runs on an external server that can only be accessed using the vpn from our PC's. 
I can access the webservice from the Android simulator without doing anything special. However I cannot access the webservice from the BlackBerry simulator -- not even from the browser of the simulator -- though I am able to connect to other services on the web from the BlackBerry simulator.

What kind settings are there to fix this?

Comment: Guys any inputs ?....Also i am able to access this webservice from any browser Mozilla/IE and Android-Browser and also from an Android App...however just unable to access this service from blackberry simulator browser and withing the blackberry app....are there some kind of settings to be done for MDS?...i am also behind a proxy so....added application.handler.http.proxyEnabled = true
application.handler.http.proxyHost = xx.x.x.xx
application.handler.http.proxyPort = xxxx...

Comment: but no idea of what to add for accessing a private IP from blackberry simulator...googled a lot...this kind of questions seems remained unanswered... Any inputs ?

Comment: Guys any inputs....am running out of ideas...tried all things possible.....made various settings for a browser in simulator...though no success....i really don't understand as to where to look for next....any pointers?...any links to look into?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a network setting for the simulator that might be useful for situations like this. You could try manually assigning the vpn ip address you were given.

```
/ip-address={string}
```

IP address of the simulated handheld. This should be left blank under normal circumstances. If running on a PC with multiple IP addresses, one can be specified here to cause the simulator to use it.

Cheers

Ray

Answer (score 1):

Ok...anyone bumping on the same problem...

Append ";deviceside=true" to the URL from which data is to be fetched